# webcomponents.js when using bower install

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

Is there a simple way to combine all the files for the webcomponents.js polyfills?  I am using polymer and there seems to be 2 major places which add significantly to the number of requests made.  webcomponents.js seems to load about 70+ files individually via javascript.  Polymer-gestures is the second place making major contributions to the number of requests but much less-so than webcomponents.js.  Does anyone have a solution for this rather than going and manually combining all the files?

Why do they not do this already? It seems a bit ridiculous.  Even if it were to break it down to 4 files for each of the major polyfill categories it would be much better.

**UPDATE:**  I am unable to get even the [example](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/concatenating-web-components.html) given on the polymer site to work, when using vulcanize to reduce requests.  I can get an image to come up fine in the custom component (working).  It works after doing vulcanize but doesn't cut down on almost any requests because most are made via script tags written from JS in webcomponents.js and polymer.js.  Doing --inline completely breaks it and component doesn't load.  Any ideas???

**UPDATE:** When attempting the example I was using resources I had already pulled for my current project.  I tried in an isolated folder and pulled resources again (bower) and it actually worked.  What I need to figure out now is breaking everything when I pull it and why?  Below are my bower.json files for the non-working case and the working case:

Broken:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "webcomponentsjs": "webcomponentsjs#master",
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#master",
    "core-drawer-panel": "Polymer/core-drawer-panel#master",
    "paper-tabs": "Polymer/paper-tabs#master",
    "core-icon-buttons": "Polymer/core-icon-button#master",
    "core-toolbar": "Polymer/core-toolbar#master",
    "core-animated-pages": "Polymer/core-animated-pages#master",
    "core-header-panel": "Polymer/core-header-panel#master"
  }
}
```

Working:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "polymer/polymer#~0.5.5",
    "webcomponentsjs": "~0.5.5"
  }
}
```

My problem is I still need to have it pull these other resources for my project as they are components I use.

Comment: when i vulcanize i use --csp --inline --strip that gives me my whole project in 2 files 1 html and 1 js.

Comment: I am totally lost on how this works for you.  I just tested again with their example on the polymer site.  I will post my exact procedure and results.  It is absolutely not working for me.  If I do --inline at all then it just breaks.

Comment: try deleting the bower_components folder and run bower again? i do not see anything in the file that looks wrong to me.  your working file and mine both have "polymer": "Polymer/polymer", as first item. i do not think that should matter. /shrug

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Actually, I found the issue.  Pulling #master was causing my problem.  I instead should have been pulling the proper version I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can Vulcanize your code based on the use of components. Detailed explanation is on the Polymer site:

https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/concatenating-web-components.html

Comment: Negative... that adds the initial JS from the script tag... it still then loads all the individual scripts via JS and doesn't prevent the original issue (webcomponents.js loading absurd amounts of individual scripts).

Comment: Ok so I did a few things testing with just the example they gave.  Doing vulcanize (no switches) cuts down the requests on the element imports only.  Doing --inline will combine all the JS as I want.  Then doing a --csp --strip moves all the JS to a single external file.  This cuts down the requests and the size significantly.  Instead of doing this in my project (I was having issues) I did this on the example from this site.

Comment: While not ideal, I can 'build' a usable monolithic JS file that is much smaller doing this to use in place of webcomponents.js which I can still conditionally load.  I will test this out and see if it works.

Comment: Another issue though... doing this... just using the --inline breaks the extremely simple example they made.  Because of this, doing a --inline at all seems to be out of the question.  So this brings me to my original question.

Comment: It seems my issue was stemming from some problem when bower is resources and nothing to do with vulcanize.

Answer (score 0):

So... I found the issue.  I was pulling #master instead of the proper versions I needed.  Fixing this pretty much solved any issues I was having.